# How to compile simple python embeded program using distutils

Tags: python, visual-c++, compilation

Here is my code:

```
from distutils.msvc9compiler import MSVCCompiler

target_python_file = "main.py"
ccode = """#include <Python.h>

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  PyObject* PyFileObject;
  putenv("PYTHONPATH=lib");
  putenv("PYTHONHOME=.");
  Py_SetProgramName(argv[0]);
  Py_Initialize();
  PyFileObject = PyFile_FromString("%s", "r");
  PyRun_SimpleFileEx(PyFile_AsFile(PyFileObject), "%s", 1);
  Py_Finalize();
  return 0;
}
""" % (target_python_file, target_python_file)

with open("main.c","w") as main:
    main.write(ccode)

compiler = MSVCCompiler()
compiler.compile(["main.c"],include_dirs=["C:/Python27/include"])
compiler.link("",["main.obj"],"python_launcher.exe",libraries=["python27"], library_dirs=["C:/Python27/libs"])
```

When I run this, `python_launcher.exe` appears, however, when I try to run it, I get not a valid win32 application error.

I can compile same code using visaul c++ 2008 and it works, but I want to utilize distutils for this, because I want it to figure out configuration options for compiler.

## Debug

I tried to open created executable in WinDebug, but I couldn't open, because this happened:
[image]

Turkish part says it is not a valid Win32 application.

Comment: What is the exact call stack you are getting?

Comment: @Abhijit I can't get a stack trace. See my updated quesiton.

Answer (score 0):

There are two modifications to your code to make it work :

1. Use link_executable to output a standalone executable (the compile.link() is useless, use the subfunctions instead).

   ```
   compiler.link_executable( ["main.obj"], #object
                              "launch"   , # strip the .exe extension, it will be added
                              libraries=["python27"],
                              library_dirs=["C:/Python27/libs"]
                            )
   ```

   At this point you should get this error message :

   ```
   X:\dev\null>python_launcher.exe 
   ImportError: No module named site
   ```

That's because you didn't entered the PYTHONPATH and PYTHONHOME variable env. in your main.c :

1. VARENV :

   ```
   putenv("PYTHONPATH=C:/Python27/Lib");
   putenv("PYTHONHOME=C:/Python27");
   ```

It should work with those fixes (tested on Windows XP x86, Python 2.7, VSExpress 2008)

The whole code :

```
from distutils.msvc9compiler import MSVCCompiler

target_python_file = "main.py"
ccode = """#include <Python.h>

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  PyObject* PyFileObject;
  putenv("PYTHONPATH=C:/Python27/Lib");
  putenv("PYTHONHOME=C:/Python27");
  Py_SetProgramName(argv[0]);
  Py_Initialize();
  PyFileObject = PyFile_FromString("%s", "r");
  PyRun_SimpleFileEx(PyFile_AsFile(PyFileObject), "%s", 1);
  Py_Finalize();
  return 0;
}
""" % (target_python_file, target_python_file)

with open("main.c","w") as main:
    main.write(ccode)

compiler = MSVCCompiler()
compiler.compile(["main.c"],include_dirs=["C:/Python27/include"])
compiler.link_executable(["main.obj"],"launch", libraries=["python27"], library_dirs=["C:/Python27/libs"])
```